# How to undo changes in .profile?

Tags: gedit, mint, .profile

I changed my ~/.profile and now I can't login.

I'm new to Linux and I was trying to add adb/fastboot (android development tools) to my PATH by editing PATH in .profile. I had done a different method before, but I'm unable to find that method again, and a lot of people tend to recommend editing .profile to add environmental variables to PATH.

Back to the problem. I try to log in, but Linux simply returns "Your session only lasted less than 10 seconds...." and then when I go to see the details, it shows...

```
syndaemon: no process found
/etc/mdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup...
/etc/mdm/Xsession: Executing cinnamon-session-cinnamon failed, will try to run x-terminal-emulator
/etc/mdm/Xsession: 205: exec: x-terminal-emulator: not found
```

I'm running 64-bit Linux Mint Cinnamon v17.3

How do I undo the changes to ~/.profile? Or how do I at least login so that I can undo the changes via gedit?

Thanks!

Comment: you're sure you changed `/home/youruser/.profile` and **not** `/etc/profile` (or anything else in `/etc/`), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>These instructions will **not** work if you edited `/etc/profile`, as those changes affect **all users**. This is why you should...</sup>

---

...be **careful** when messing with your user's path, and make sure to make a copy of mission-critical files you edit!

---

1. Reboot your machine.
2. At the login screen, where you would normally type your password, hold **Control and Alt**, then press **F1**.
3. At the login prompt, type `root`, and enter `tooroot` for the password.

   - if you get a message saying you are unable to be logged in as this user, login as yourself with your own password and try to run `/usr/bin/sudo su` (typed just like that) as your own user.
     If this also fails, you will need to use a LiveCD or other external media to recover.
4. If you're logged in as root at this point, `cd` to your user's directory in `/home`. If you are the only user, your folder will be the only folder  in `/home`.

   - Note that if your user's home directory is encrypted, all of this becomes a lot harder.
5. Once the output of `pwd` shows you're sitting in your user's directory (and **you've ensured that there's nothing important in any of the following files as they will be destroyed forever**), type `rm .profile .bash_profile .bashrc`.
6. Type exactly `cp /etc/skel/.profile ./.profile`.
7. Type `reboot`, then wait for your machine to come up again. Try to log in; if it works: yay! if not, you should get a Live CD and mount your hard disk from the Live CD (or other Linux installation??) and delete the files from there.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering so quickly! I was able to get to step 5 as my own user, not as root user. Unfortunately, when i type in `rm .profile -bash_profile .bashrc` , I get "rm: invalid option -- 'b' [next line] Try 'rm --help' for more information."

Comment: @Colton no problem! Has it worked?

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter too soon. Please look above to see what I meant to say :)

Comment: @Colton I typed a `-` instead of a `.`, sorry. `rm` thinks `-` indicates an option. try `rm .profile .bash_profile .bashrc` instead

Comment: Haha thank you so much. I saw the `-` and was confused, but again I'm fairly new to Linux, so I didn't bother to question it. Your method worked great! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Colton I'm glad I could help!